# Cordova JQuery Error VS2015: Exception: Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting this Error in VS when i load an html with jquery.mobile:

> Exception: Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined
>
> jquery.mobile-1.4.5js

I followed this tutorial: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/-this-xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-style-information-associated
for getting started with jQuery.

This is an example of an html throwing this exception:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://api.openweathermap.org https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bb_Performance_Test_Page.css">
    <title>Performance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
        <h1 id="app-title">Performance</h1>
    </div>

    <button name="bb_prime_Button"
            onClick="bb_prime_Button_Click_Event()">
    Get Prime
    </button>
    <div class="prime">
        noData
    </div>
    <div class="time">
        noData
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bb_Performance_Test_Page.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, an Hybrid (Cordova) App Project, JQuery3.1.0 and JQuery.mobile.1.4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some functions of `jquery.mobile-1.4.5` not be compatible with `jquery-3.1.0` .Use `jquery-2.2.4` version . You can download from here [link](https://code.jquery.com/)