# Saving Data with Ajax Call to WebService with Json as Parameter is not working In Cordova Project for Android

Tags: android, json, ajax, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to make a Anroid Mobile Application to Save Data to a Remote SQL Database. I am using Cordova Project in Visual Studio 2015. I have a Webservice which is working fine and taking Name, Phone & Profile information and saving data in SQL Server properly. Now I am trying to call this WebService from Android Mobile Application but $Ajax Call to webservice is not working. The control is not reaching to the Webservice.

I have already added WhiteSpace Plugin but its still not working.

Here is the original html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">      
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }
            function onDeviceReady() { alert("Device is Ready to User"); }
            function SaveContact() {
                var Contact = new Object();
                Contact.Name = "Harvinder";
                Contact.Phone = "9819862717";
                Contact.Profile = "Director"
                var myData = JSON.stringify(Contact);
                var myURL = "http://gsecurity.net/JsonDAL.asmx/SaveContact";
                alert(typeof (myData));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", url: myURL, data: myData, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) { alert("Success"); },
                    error: function (e, status) { alert("Failed:"  + e.statusText); }
                });}
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <h1>Call Ajax to Save Json Data with WebService</h1>
        <button onclick="SaveContact();">Click Here to Save Test Contact</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the modified code as per suggestions which is still not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() { alert("Version 1.10 is Ready"); }
            $.support.ajax = true;
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            function SaveContact() {
                var Contact = new Object();
                Contact.Name = "Harvinder";
                Contact.Phone = "9819862717";
                Contact.Profile = "Director";
                var myData = JSON.stringify(Contact);
                var myURL = "http://gsecurity.net/JsonDAL.asmx/SaveContact";
                alert("DataType:" + typeof (myData));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json",
                    url: myURL, data: myData, allowCrossDomainPages: true,                 
                    success: function (msg) { alert("Success"); },
                    error: function (e, status) { alert("Failed:"  + e.statusText); }
                });
                alert("Completed");
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Call Ajax to Save Json Data with WebService</h2>
    <button onclick="SaveContact()">Click Here to Save Test Contact</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Webservice is Here which is working fine when accessed directly by url

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")>
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class JsonDAL
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <WebMethod>
    Public Function SaveContact(Name As String, Phone As String, Profile As String) As String
        Try
            Dim ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Data").ConnectionString
            Dim Con = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
            Dim Qry = "INSERT INTO Contacts (Name,Phone,Profile) VALUES ('" + Name + "','" + Phone + "','" + Profile + "')"
            Dim Cmd = New SqlCommand(Qry, Con)
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Con.Open()
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Con.Close()
            Return "Done"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many mistakes in your code.You don't need to add deviceReady event OnLoad event etc etc. I modified your code try this.Check your database I added one record name="TestFromHomen"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">  
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
            function onDeviceReady() {
   alert("Device is Ready to User");
   }
            function SaveContact() {
                var Contact = new Object();
                Contact.Name = "Harvinder";
                Contact.Phone = "9819862717";
                Contact.Profile = "Director"
                var myData = JSON.stringify(Contact);
                var myURL = "http://gsecurity.net/JsonDAL.asmx/SaveContact";
                alert(typeof (myData));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
     url: myURL,
     data: myData,
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) { alert("Success"); },
                    error: function (e, status) { alert("Failed:"  + e.statusText); }
                });
    }
   
    
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Call Ajax to Save Json Data with WebService</h1>
        <button onclick="SaveContact()">Click Here to Save Test Contact</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/appBundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response.I copied your code as it is but its still not working. I installed .apk in my Android Phone but its not going beyond the line alert(typeof (myData)). I saw one record TestFromHomen is added in database. When I Run code snipped above its giving error 
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 33,
  "colno": 17
}

Comment: Are jquery and jqury mobile js file in the scripts folder?

Comment: Yes both the .js files are there. The same code works fine in normal asp.net project but its not working in Cordova project. That means the code and webservice are perfect. I guess something is wrong somewhere which is stopping the android app to access external URL. I  changed the meta tag also but its still not working.

Comment: I also added $.support.ajax = true;  $.support.cors = true;           $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;  But its still not working. $ajax is failing.

Comment: This is my Final Code which includes various suggesions

Comment: use jqury lower version. you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38644996/5887638

Comment: YES Homen Its working with lower version. Thanks a Lot. You are really a champion Homen. How to mark this suggestion as accepted

Comment: Your Suggestion to use lower version is ACCEPTED. Its working now. Thanks Homen.